# Wordpress add_attachment hook not returning metata

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hook into WordPress after the file is uploaded and metadata is created.  Currently I am using the following code.

```
add_action( 'add_attachment', array($this,'ProcessFile') );

public function ProcessFile( $attachment_id )
{
    $Images     = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id );
}
```

However, $Images returns false which means the metadata has not been created. What hook should I be using to get the metadata of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have analysis your requirement, you can try to below code and follow instruction:

`add_attachment` runs right after an attachment is added to your website database and before the metadata have been generated. If you don't need the value to be in the database yet, you can use the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` filter to hook in. However, if you need the data to be in the database already, you'll have to use `updated_post_meta` and check that the `meta_key` passed in equals `_wp_attachment_metadata`.